# Find the sum of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: programming-challenge, elixir

I have already done many of the Project Euler questions in other languages before, but whenever learning a new language, I like to do the problems again in that language.

Here is my elixir version of

> Find the sum of all Fibonacci numbers below 4,000,000.

```
stream = Stream.unfold({0,1}, fn {a, b} -> {a, {b, a + b}} end)
Enum.reduce_while(stream, 0, &(
    cond do
        &1 < 4000000 and rem(&1, 2) == 0 ->
            {:cont, &2 + &1}
        &1 < 4000000 ->
            {:cont, &2}
        true ->
            {:halt, &2}
    end
))
```

Can anyone spot a way to make my code fit the elixir paradigm more? Are there things I could improve?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, if this isn't the purpose of this site then what is?

Comment: Someone has voted to close it as "Unclear what you're asking". I don't see why this would be considered unclear though, and this looks very much ontopic.

Comment: Someone seems to have raised a "Unclear what you're asking" close vote. But you have added that to your question since then, so your question should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'd improve two things:

- take advantage of [ability](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/13b5e53efadd2b6b66d05fcb4aa526fa74672762/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L1559) to specify multiple clauses for anonymous function,
- use [underscore](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/3c001a569d0c63843b3791859147e01658759843/lib/elixir/pages/Syntax%20Reference.md#numbers) for big numbers to improve code readability.

My take on your code:

```
{0, 1}
|> Stream.unfold(fn {a, b} -> {a, {b, a + b}} end)
|> Enum.reduce_while(0, fn
  value, acc when value < 4_000_000 and rem(value, 2) == 0 -> {:cont, acc + value}
  value, acc when value < 4_000_000 -> {:cont, acc}
  _value, acc -> {:halt, acc}
end)
```

Comment: Also, I like your use of an explicit `fn` over the submitters `&`- the latter is often hard to read and usually I will only use it for very short stuff, probably just the `&function/arity` construct and nothing else.